# Interval Scheduling Confusion

Tags: greedy-algorithms, intervals

I am reading some notes about interval scheduling. I gives the following diagram:
[image]

and states that:

r2 is compatible with r3, while r2 and r1 are conflicting. Similarly, the set {r1, r3, r4} is compatible, while {r2, r3, r4} is not compatible.

I can understand that set (r1, r3, r4) is compatible. How (r2, r3, r4) are not compatible. Since they are not overlapping, isn't they are compatible?

Comment: Maybe there was some spelling error? Could you credit your sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an error in your notes.  {r2,r3,r4} are compatible.